# Cucumber step definition with asterisk

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumber-java

We have feature files that have long tests that validate multiple things written in non-english language, the `Given -> When -> Then` structure doesn't make sense.
I tried replacing feature file keywords with `*`, and that works just fine, however here are the problems:

1. When writing a new step in a form of `* Some step`, and using Alt->Enter shortcut to generate a step definition, IntelliJ IDEA does... Nothing. It only opens the file where I wanted to put the definition without any added code. I've updated IDE and plugins to be latest.
2. There doesn't seem to be any way to have a "universal" annotation to use for asterisk steps, only `Given`, `When`, `Then`, `And`, `But` exists. It's not very logical to have a `* Some step` feature and `@Given("Some step")` definition.

Is there any workaround that I might use?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to file a feature request with Cucumber for a universal step definition annotation. Something like `@Step`.

Comment: Also sounds like you should file a bug report with IDEA.

Comment: Wasn't sure, but since the second opinion is exactly what I was thinking, then maybe I will do just that, thanks. Will still leave the question open, in case there is a workaround from someone in the mean time.

Comment: What's the natural language that you are using? And what's the cucumber version you are using?

Comment: @AlexeyR. - Latvian. And cucumber version is 6.10.4.

Comment: So you need the same as Given When Then but written in your language? Like "duota, kai, tada"?

Comment: Or you just need a way to introduce some very custom key words?

Comment: No, as I said - using my native language will not make sense due to test specifics. The problem is using step in feature file with asterisk and connecting that to a logical annotation in step definition, and using step definition generation.

Comment: In any case, following @M.P.Korstanje advice, filed a feature request - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with few coding steps.

0. Say you have the scenario like this:

```
Feature: Generic annotation

  Scenario: Testing annotations
    * having asterix
    * use custom generic annotation
```

1. Add custom annotation to your sources

```java
package click.webelement.cucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.StepDefinitionAnnotation;
import io.cucumber.java.StepDefinitionAnnotations;
import org.apiguardian.api.API;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@StepDefinitionAnnotation
@Documented
@Repeatable(MyStep.MySteps.class)
@API(status = API.Status.STABLE)
public @interface MyStep {

    String value();

    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @StepDefinitionAnnotations
    @Documented
    @interface MySteps {
        MyStep[] value();
    }
}
```

3. Now use it in your Step Definition

```java
package click.webelement.cucumber;

public class StepDef {

    @MyStep("having asterix")
    public void doOne(){
        System.out.println("Running having asterix");
    }

    @MyStep("use custom generic annotation")
    public void doTwo(){
        System.out.println("Running use custom generic annotation");
    }

}
```

**UPD**

In order to make your Idea plugin work with your custom annotation you need to place that annotation to

`io.cucumber.java.LANG`  package where *LANG* is the sub-package for your chosen language.

To make everything work as default you place it to

`io.cucumber.java.en`

Comment: This functionally works as I would expect, great, however - IntelliJ IDEA doesn't understand the connection between this step in feature file and its definition, it shows `Undefined step reference` warning, control+click doesn't navigate to the step and `Create step definition` intent doesn't function. 
Any ideas how to remedy that as well?

Comment: Yes, idea wouldn't work with that unfortunately. It's plugin expects  standard annotation set

Comment: @Arcca I have an idea how to overcome that but I'll test it later today.

Comment: @Arcca I managed to make it work. See my update.

Comment: This is about 95% of a complete function that I wanted, thanks a lot! Now only the step generation is missing, but I can live with that.